# Foreman: Command "start" is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreman

I'm getting the above error when trying to run `foreman start` from command line.

I installed the gem:

```
gem install foreman
```

Then defined a procfile. Why am I getting this error? When I run foreman list, I get:

```
Available commands:
  build         Commission Forman to build a new Laravel app for you
  help          Displays help for a command
  list          Lists commands
  scaffold      Generate a scaffolded Foreman template file
  self-update   Updates the application.
```

Comment: weird. I always use foreman start. what do you get when you run foreman run?

Comment: [InvalidArgumentException]  Command "run" is not defined.

Comment: looks like you have multiple ruby versions. please check rvm-list and select approprite ruby version. also if you post logs that will be helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/Indatus/foreman you use different foreman :)
https://github.com/ddollar/foreman it's what you need